# About jQuery, why does the mouseenter() on a <input> not work?

Tags: jquery, mouseenter

Thanks for checking my post first!

The `mouseenter()` is working for the tag h2, but it does not work on the `<input>`. Could you tell what is wrong with my code?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("h2").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");
  });

  $("input").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h2>Select Gaming Time:</h2>
  <form method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="time" value="5">5 Minute (Hard) &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="time" value="8">8 Minutes (Normal) &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="time" value="10">10 Minutes (Easy)
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want your radio button to turn green or the text next to it?

Comment: It's working on the input elements http://jsfiddle.net/5wbLnaep/

Comment: @ Tushar: The inputs are radio's, not text. Radios can't be styled that much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently trying to turn the radio button's background green. Unfortunately this can't be done. You can however wrap the text next to the radios in a label and turn the label's background green.

As an added benefit you can make the label clickable as well using the `for=""` attribute and corresponding `id=""`s.

Also, **this can be done using css only** `h2:hover, label:hover { background- color: green; }`. Saving you a lot of bytes to load!

A. Wolff's code copied over from this jsfiddle:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("h2").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "green");
    });

    $("label:has(:radio)").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "green");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    
<h2>Select Gaming Time:</h2>

    <form method="post">
        <label for="time_5">
            <input type="radio" name="time" value="5" id="time_5">5 Minute (Hard) &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        <label for="time_8">
            <input type="radio" name="time" value="8" id="time_8">8 Minutes (Normal) &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        <label for="time_10">
            <input type="radio" name="time" value="10" id="time_10">10 Minutes (Easy)</label>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Wolff, I was about to create the code and add it to the post. Your fiddle saved me some time, plus your `has(:radio)` is real nice!

Answer (score 0):

Well to avoid your confusion that `mouseenter` doesn't works on input type elements . This is not so . It works . You can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5wbLnaep/1/) . As said above in the answer , it is better to do the `css` change to the text next to radio button .